# Not adding data to the database?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

So I am fairly new to php I have some php code that confirms a user has been added into a group and then submits their information into the database but it doesn't seem to be adding all the information

```
<?php
/* Verifies member being added
*/
require 'db.php';
session_start();

 // Make sure join code and email aren't empty
 if(isset($_GET['joincode']) && !empty($_GET['joincode']) AND isset($_GET['memberemail']) && !empty($_GET['memberemail']))
{ 
$joincode = $link->escape_string($_GET['joincode']);
$memberemail = $link->escape_string($_GET['memberemail']);


  // Select user with matching email
  $result = $link->query("SELECT * FROM logins WHERE Email='$memberemail'");


    if ( $result->num_rows !==1 )
    {
    $_SESSION['message'] = "You need to create an account or the URL is invalid!";

    header("location: error.php");

    }
   else {
    $_SESSION['message'] = "You have been added!";


   while ($id = $result->fetch_assoc()){

    $id['unique_id'];
    }


    $leagueinfo = $link->query("SELECT * FROM leagues WHERE joincode='$joincode'");

    $info = $leagueinfo->fetch_assoc();
      $info['league_id'];
      $info['league_name'];
      $info['start_date'];
      $info['end_date'];




    $sql = "INSERT INTO leagues (unique_id, league_id, league_name, role, start_date, end_date, joincode) "
  . "VALUES ('".$id['unique_id']."','".$info['league_id']."','".$info['league_name']."','MEMBER',
  '".$info['start_date']."','".$info['end_date']."','".$joincode."')";

      mysqli_query($link,$sql);

    //  header("location: success.php");
   }
  }
else {
 $_SESSION['message'] = "Invalid parameters provided for account verification!";
header("location: error.php");
}
  ?>
```

I've changed the names of the different queries and it's now pulling all information **except for the unique_id** which echoes out correctly but isn't being added into the database.

Comment: Do you get an error message?

Comment: Make use of [mysqli error reporting](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php) and stick to either using objects or procedural, don't mix them. Your query is highly vulnerable to mysql injection, you should switch to using [prepare](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead of query

Comment: I don't get an error message, it goes into the database but only the joining code and role go in

Comment: @whoisthis You should not modify your question using the answers given as that way the answers will not make any sense any more. Instead, add below your question what you have changed and what kind of problems still remain.

Comment: By the way, in the modified code you posted, you were not yet using the new `$info` variable in the INSERT query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are overwriting your `$row` variable when you fetch a result from the `$leagueinfo` query.

You should use different names for these result sets.

Also note that this is a very strange way to get a result set:

```
# Why are you using $row = $row = ... ?
while ($row = $row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
    $row['unique_id'];
}
```

The line in the loop does not do anything and you you will always end up with `$row` containing the results of the last iteration of the loop.

It would make more sense to check if the number of rows is 1 and throw an error if it is not. Then you can simply fetch 1 row without using a loop:

```
if ($result->num_rows !== 1) {
    # Handle error for example by throwing an exception
}
# You need an else if you don't return from a method or throw an exception
$row = $result->fetch_assoc();
```

You also have an sql injection problem: You are escaping the values for the SELECT statements, but not for the INSERT. I would recommend using prepared statements everywhere instead of using escaping.